# How to keep track of a purchase total based on number of clicks

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I am trying to keep track of a running total based on number of clicks on the buttons on the site. There are 8 buttons, all of which should add $123.45 to the total when clicked, as well as alert the total.

Some of my HTML

```
<article class="dog-card">
  <img src="images/murphy-card.jpg" alt="a brown and white dog with a questioning look on his face" onclick="dogInfo('Murphy', 'Mix', '$123.45')">
  <h3>Murphy</h3>
  <p><strong>Cost to Adopt:</strong> $123.45</p>
  <p>Corrum volorit iandae nimaxim cum restia volor reicid ut et etur sunt arum rendae pla endis re ea erum, qui doluptae</p>
  <p class="adopt" onclick="addFee()">Adopt</p>
</article>
```

And my JS so far

```
function addFee() {
  let x = 123.45;
  let total = ('Your total is $' + x);

  alert(total);
}
```

I know this JS isn't what I need, but I just wanted to put something in so I could verify the button was working.

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So why can't you do newTotal = 123.45 + currentTotal and keep a globally scoped variable for each "button"?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I'm not sure what you mean by "a globally scoped variable". If I knew how to keep track of the number of clicks or running total, I do think that would work! I apologize, I'm very very new to JS.

Comment: So above addFree function, put let LastTotal = 0; and then output that variable instead, add to it each time the total!

Comment: Made a comment you can try that at first, and when you add more buttons sort your variables then? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let LastTotal = 0;

function addFee() {
  lastTotal = lastTotal + 123.45;
  alert("Your total is $" + lastTotal);
}
```